# Adding a class on focus of an input, not click

Tags: jquery

I have created a nice little input field which pushes the label field above the input on click. I have tried changing the JS to "focus" but it is not working.

I need to do this so that when people are tabbing from one field to another the same effect applies.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j71ghw2b/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
     <label>Your email</label><br>
     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name-text"><input type="text" name="name-text" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( ".form-row" ).each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            $(this).addClass('active-field');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the class to the `input` or the `.form-row`? I ask due to the ambiguous use of `each()`

Comment: There is above 6 inputs, so i need to it to apply to each form row, not all of them

Comment: So... you want the class to be added to the `.form-row`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `.each()` loop.

Just listen to the `focus` event on your inputs and add the class to the `closest()` `.form-row`.

```js
$(".form-row input").on('focus', function() {
  $(this).closest(".form-row").addClass('active-field');
});
```

```css
.active-field{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
     <label>Your email</label><br>
     <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name-text"><input type="text" name="name-text" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/j71ghw2b/13/

```
$( ".form-row input" ).on("focus click", function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active-field');
});
```

No need to .each.
And the event `focus` just work for inputs.